# Cannot read property of NULL in Jquery Datatables

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I am Satya, trying to get the data from the database and displaying the data in the Jquery datatables.

I have included my code below. Here the scenario is when I am trying to get sql query data without any where clause. I am able to display data in datatable, when I included where clause it is showing: `Cannot read property error of null`, I tried a lot to fix that, even I getting data from php to javascript page through ajax but it is not getting data to datatables, here is my code:

## Jquery:

```
$("<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style:'text-align:center;'>"
    +"<thead>"
    +"<tr>"
    +"<th>EID</th>"
    +"<th>EMICH_EMAIL</th>"
    +"<th>FIRSTNAME</th>"
    +"<th>LASTNAME</th>"
    +"<th>SIGN_IN</th>"
    +"<th>SIGN_OUT</th>"
    +"<th>DURATION</th>"
    +"</tr>"
    +"</thead>"
    +"<tbody>").appendTo('#table-section');
    $('#example').dataTable({           
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
                   "sSwfPath":"http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },         
        "bProcessing": false,
        "sAjaxDataProp":'',
        "sAjaxSource":"fetchdata.php"
    });
```

## PHP:

```
<?php
    include 'dataconnection.php';

    $user_id=$_POST['eid'];
    $from=$_POST['startdate'];
    $to=$_POST['enddate'];

    $students_data="select st.EID,st.emich_email,firstname,lastname,sign_in,sign_out, " +
    "SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(sign_out,sign_in))) AS totalduration from "+
    "student_details st INNER JOIN scans sc ON st.emich_email = sc.emich_email where st.EID ='$user_id'";

    $students_data_query=mysqli_query($connection,$students_data);

if($students_data_query){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($students_data_query)){

    $output[]=array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6]);
}
echo json_encode($output);
//echo $user_id;
}else
echo die("The error is:".mysqli_error($connection));
?>
```

Comment: You need to treat the NULL values​​. In your query, put the `IFNULL()` function.

Comment: Hello Fernando I dont have any NUll values in the data, even after getting the data from the database, I just alert them on the screen and I didnt find any null values, but the data is not getting displayed in datatables. I am so thankful to you for taking time at my question.

Comment: Hummm... I understand.. What format the JSON is coming out?

Comment: Hello Fernando,I am getting in the following way, [["Bank Deposits","12345.4567","3456.90","3456.435"],["Travel","98712.67","2458.90","3981.25"]], here each block of values are single row in datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karthik, try this. For me, it works perfectly.

```
<?php
include 'dataconnection.php';

$user_id = $_POST ['eid'];
$from = $_POST ['startdate'];
$to = $_POST ['enddate'];

if (isset ( $_POST ['eid'] )) {
    // Descrição se $_POST['truc'] existe

    /* Table Columns */
    $aColumns = array (
            'EID',
            'EMICH_EMAIL',
            'FIRSTNAME',
            'LASTNAME',
            'SIGN_IN',
            'SIGN_OUT',
            'TOTALDURATION' 
    );

    $students_data = "select st.EID,st.emich_email,firstname,lastname,sign_in,sign_out, " + 
        "SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(sign_out,sign_in))) AS totalduration from " + 
        "student_details st INNER JOIN scans sc ON st.emich_email = sc.emich_email where st.EID ='$user_id'";

    $students_data_query = mysqli_query ( $connection, $students_data );

    $output = array (
            "aaData" => array () 
    );

    if ($students_data_query) {
        $row = array ();
        while ( $aRow = mysqli_fetch_array ( $students_data_query ) ) {
            for($i = 0; $i < count ( $aColumns ); $i ++) {
                if ($aColumns [$i] != ' ') {
                    // Charset for accentuation.
                    $row [] = iconv ( "iso-8859-1", "utf-8", $aRow [$aColumns [$i]] );
                }
            }
            $output ['aaData'] [] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode ( $output );
    } else
        echo die ( "The error is:" . mysqli_error ( $connection ) );
} else {
    echo die ( "The error is: S_POST [eid] IS NULL" );
}
?>
```

## Jquery:

```
$("<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style:'text-align:center;'>"
    +"<thead>"
    +"<tr>"
    +"<th>EID</th>"
    +"<th>EMICH_EMAIL</th>"
    +"<th>FIRSTNAME</th>"
    +"<th>LASTNAME</th>"
    +"<th>SIGN_IN</th>"
    +"<th>SIGN_OUT</th>"
    +"<th>DURATION</th>"
    +"</tr>"
    +"</thead>"
    +"<tbody>").appendTo('#table-section');
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
                   "sSwfPath":"http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },         
        "bProcessing": false,
        "sAjaxDataProp":'',
        "sAjaxSource":"fetchdata.php",
        "aoColumns" : [
                    {
                        "sTitle": "EID",
                        "aTargets": [0]
                    },     
                    {
                        "sTitle": "EMICH_EMAIL",
                        "aTargets": [1]
                    },
                    {
                        "sTitle": "FIRSTNAME",
                        "aTargets": [2]
                    },
                    {
                        "sTitle": "LASTNAME",
                        "aTargets": [3]
                    },
                    {
                        "sTitle": "SIGN_IN",
                        "aTargets": [4]
                    },
                    {
                        "sTitle": "SIGN_OUT",
                        "aTargets": [5]
                    },
                    {
                        "sTitle": "DURATION",
                        "aTargets": [6]
                    }]
    });
```

Comment: Yeah Just give me few minutes, I will let you know fernando.

Comment: Or try based on this example. It is similar to your case. [POST data - Server Side](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html)

Comment: Hello Fernando, I am just wondering where did you declare $aRow in the code, even i got the warning for that.

Comment: Can you just give me 30 mins of time, I have meeting right now, i will try that and let you know and thanks a lot fernando for taking time , I mean it

Comment: Hello Fernando, do the aColumns array values should be matching with case sensitive in Database columns, or are those user defined because I get an error at iconv statement stating that eid is undefined index .

Comment: Try to remove the iconv, use only: `$row [] = $aRow [$aColumns [$i]];`.

Comment: Still getting the same error, also do I have to anything in Jquery code ?

Comment: I've Added some more information to Jquery font. Make a test.

Comment: Sure before that I would like to tell you one thing, I am sending data request through Ajax to the another php page, it mean the Jquery code is in another page and PHP code is in another page, I think this is the reason it is getting failed, I am not sure about that Fernanado

Comment: No no. The PHP should even be on another page. Make a test, and if it goes wrong. Tell me what. And it was in PHP or Jquery.

Comment: $row [$i] = $aRow [$aColumns[$i]]; I think this is the line where I am getting failed, the error is undefined index, here my idea is if we try to access them out of isset it will be reporting undefined index, I handled that using error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); but now I am getting null values in data and the data is in below format {"0":{"aaData":[]},"aaData":[["bankDdeposits",null,null,"0.0000000",null]]}, to be frank I dont have any null data in the database

Comment: Hello Fernando,is there any way that I can contact through email, I am sorry if It is trouble for you.

Comment: Not. This error is related to S_POST be empty. I've added a trigger. Make a test.

Comment: You are the lifesaver, I have sent you email, please take a look at that, hatsoff for your patience for dealing seamlessly with me for last two hours, Thanks a lot, it worked for me, I need to do small modification in changing the div tag id and all so I will do them .